# How to set embedding layer name in keras

Tags: python, keras, embedding

```
inputs_bedding = Input(shape=(it.shape))   
embedding = Embedding(9488, 512, trainable=False)(inputs_bedding)
```

There is no `name` parameter in keras Embedding layer. How to set the name to the layer?

Comment: model.summary() prints the layers

Comment: Thank you Ravid, I need to set a specific name for Embedding layer in Keras, Is there a way? something like this Dense(9488, activation='softmax', name='logit')

Comment: What makes you think the Embedding layer has no name parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the name of the embedding layer just like any other layer.

```
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
from keras import Model


inputs_bedding = Input(shape=(32,)) 
embedding = Embedding(9488, 512, trainable=False, name="test")(inputs_bedding)

model = Model(inputs=inputs_bedding, outputs=embedding)
```

model.summary() gives you:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
test (Embedding)             (None, 32, 512)           4857856   
=================================================================
Total params: 4,857,856
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 4,857,856
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Great. Thank you, VegardKT